# how to join the T-Box with the A-Box of this Ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I found this online Book ontology http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/opdm/book.html#

OWL Schema can be downloaded here:
http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/opdm/book.owl

RDF dump can be found here

http://eelst.cs.unibo.it/apps/LODE/source?url=http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/opdm/book_example.owl

I tried to copy past the RDF dump into the owl schema file, and then run protege and upload the resulting owl file, but I didn't see the instances, (i mean I didn't see the rdf dump data)

Any way to join them please?

I would like to open the resulting owl file in Protoge, and see  the values for the instances and edit them and add more instances and so on

Comment: RDF != OWL. You cannot simply merge an RDF dataset with an OWL ontology. Protege works on OWL, which has typed entities. You could load the RDF dump in Protege first, then you will see what data can be parsed to OWL. In your example, you'll have some OWL individuals then and a lots of annotation properties because the properties from external ontologies are used, but those ontologies need to be added via imports such that a parser can determine the type of the property.

Comment: Ok, I saw that the ontology is also just plain RDF. Again, you could load the schema into Protege and see which information is as expected. But again, the imports are missing.

Comment: And you don't see the instance values for the instances because all properties will be typed as annotation properties, thus, you will probably see the data in the annotations view.

Comment: RDF graphs are just *sets* of triples.  One very simple approach would be be to just convert both RDF files to N-TRIPLES format (which has just one triple per line) and concatenate them into a single file.  Then you'd have combined them.  But in order for the instance data to be interpreted correctly, it would need to have appropriate declarations (e.g., with resources declared as owl:NamedIndividuals).  Even though the instance data uses some IRIs that are declared in the ontology doesn't mean that the instance data is an OWL ontology.

Answer (score 0):

RDF graphs are just *sets* of triples.  One very simple approach to combine the RDF would be be to just convert both RDF files to N-TRIPLES format (which has just one triple per line) and concatenate them into a single file.  Then you'd have combined them.

But in order for the instance data to be interpreted correctly, it would need to have appropriate declarations (e.g., with resources declared as owl:NamedIndividuals).  Even though the instance data uses some IRIs that are declared in the ontology doesn't mean that the instance data is an OWL ontology.